# Electron based apps hang on resume

Tags: lenovo, 19.10, electron

Whenever I resume my laptop, [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) based apps (slack, gitkraken) hang and use around 10% cpu.

After a while I get a dialog about the app not responding where I can then "Force Quit" the application or "Wait" if i wait, nothing happens for a while and the dialog show up again.

It's a Lenovo P52S laptop with Ubuntu 19.10. I believe I also had the issue with 19.04, 18.10, 18.04

Both apps are installed as snaps, so it could perhaps also be a snapd thing?

Any tips on how to fix it or clues on how investigate what is going on?

Best regards Jens

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling the snap and reinstalling with dpkg, the problem seems resolved, so I suspect this is a snap issue.

Update: I was too quick, it still happens when running slack from an installed .deb, so it is probably not snap related.